# Is it possible to extract desktop environments from an Ubuntu derivative Distro to an installed ubuntu installation

Tags: 13.10

And if you can how is it accomplished? I would like to know if this is possible to accomplish from a live USB to an install without Internet?

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to put a desktop environment onto a computer without a internet connection I would do the following. Find the package name you would use if you had the internet. We will call this PACKAGENAME. On the computer without the internet run:

```
sudo apt-get -qq --print-uris install PACKAGENAME | cut -d\' -f 2 > urls.txt
```

This should save the urls of the .deb packages it wants for the install to the file urls.txt. Go to another machine and download these packages onto a USB.

Put the USB into the computer you want to install on. Navigate to the USB folder, or move the files onto the computer and navigate to this folder in the terminal and run:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

This should install all the .deb files you downloaded. Once it is done you should be able to logout and then choose the desktop environment and log back in.

Comment: But let's say that the computer I have internet on is a Windows OS computer, what would I do then? The only computer I have that I can use any Linux OS on is the computer that does not have an internet connection.

Comment: You can still download the .deb from the url. You are only downloading the file to put it on the USB stick, youa re not trying to install it.